# can't animate with the latest 2.8 release version for mac

Tags: osx, eevee-render-engine

So I wanna test the eevee render with the latest 2.8 version for mac, and when I tried to animate the objects it doesn't move according to the keyframes. Is that a bug that is yet to be fixed, or it's just because I did something wrong?

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that you won't get support for 2.8 here until it becomes official. Its simply unfinished, so any answer will be outdated almost immediately. Sorry. Try twitter instead?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about experimental development software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that myself today. I went back to an older version of 2.8 to let me render some animation using Eevee (I had a build from the start of April I think). Cycles took 10 hours to render the frames. Eevee took 16 minutes.